# Android Workers thread

Tags: android, android-thread, android-workmanager

I'm using WorkManager in my application, is there any chance to force using same thread on each Worker instance? I'm doing operations from those Worker on my list and I need to be sure that they will be in a proper order. I know that there is `ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE` but it is working only when Worker is pending not already started.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm doing operations from those Worker on my list and I need to be sure that they will be in a proper order

`WorkManager` does not guarantee the order in which work gets done. Either:

- There should be only one piece of work that does everything (so the "proper order" is simply your own logic in `doWork()`), or
- You need to change your application logic such that the work can be performed in any order